# After closing jQuery dialog, jQuery Grid does not refresh

Tags: jquery-ui, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a jQuery Grid that loads the data on web API call, onclick of Edit button that is in each row of the grid, it takes the Id of the record and a jQuery dialog opens that loads a partialview that contains all the details of that record, On the dialog I Edit the data and Update the database. In the database the data are updated properly.But the grid Does not refresh after the dialog closes.

I have a dropdown also on the page that causes the filteration of data in the jQuery grid based on it's selection.It works fine always but after the dialog closes and On change of this dropdown list selection the request to the web API to load the grid with updated data does not go.

Answer (score 0):

Once the update is successfull, try calling `$('#id_of_the_grid').trigger('reloadGrid');` before you close the dialog.